# My code does not compile for a strange reason

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicule {
public:
    void affiche() const {
        cout << "Ceci est un vehicule." << endl;
    }

protected:
    int m_prix;
};

class Voiture : public Vehicule {
public:
    void affiche() const {
        cout << "Ceci est une voiture." << endl;
    }

private:
    int m_portes;
};

class Moto : public Vehicule {
public:
    void affiche() const {
        cout << "Ceci est une moto." << endl;
    }

private:
    double m_vitesse;
};

void presenter(Vehicule v) {
    v.affiche();
}

int main() {
    Vehicule v;
    presenter(v);

    Moto m;
    presenter(m);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't compile. Do you know why? Visual Studio says that m and v and used but not initialized. But aren't they? I mean, I initialize them.

This code doesn't compile. I repeat. It DOES NOT compile.

And the ERRORS I get (NOT warning, it's an ERROR) are:

uninitialized local variable 'm' used
uninitialized local variable 'v' used

Comment: Speak in english - écrit en anglais.

Comment: What error are you getting? It should compile.

Comment: Visual Studio complains about that "m" and "v" are local variables used but not initialized. But they are!

Comment: @Deneuve Do you actually get an error? If so, what is it exactly?

Comment: Visual Studio gives me the error C4700

Comment: @Deneuve Is that all it says - *C4700* - nothing after it? Are you intentionally being obtuse? Please copy-paste the entire error message when posting a question!

Comment: There is a difference between a warning and an error. A variable that is uninitialize most probably yields only a warning.

Comment: Erreur 2 error C4700: variable locale 'm' non initialisée utilisée c:\users\damien\documents\programmation\visual studio\projects\polymorphisme\main.cpp 43

Comment: Just a meta question: How on earth did you not notice that this is an *English* speaking website?

Comment: Closed as too localized?  What?  This seems like something that a lot of beginners might stumble on.

Comment: Bn j'sais pas m'aitrise pas torp l'anglais donc j'ose pas m'aventurer à l'utiliser vala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C4700 is a warning, not an error. Your code compiles fine. It is just telling you that the members `m_vitesse`, `m_portes`, and `m_prix` are left uninitialized. If you want to initialize them, you'll need to give those classes their own constructors, such as:

```
class Vehicule {
public:
    // This constructor initializes m_prix to 0
    Vehicule() : m_prix(0) { }

    void affiche() const {
        cout << "Ceci est un vehicule." << endl;
    }

protected:
    int m_prix;
};
```

Comment: My code doesn't compile... And the warning (which is indicated as an error in my Visual Studio) is addressed to m and v, not m_prix, m_portes and m_vitesse...

Comment: @Deneuve Well they are members of `m` and `v`. Just try it, please.

Answer (score 1):

You code do compiles however you get warnings. Because `Vehicule` laks default constructor that will initialize m_prix. You can fix it by adding construtor to it.

```
class Vehicule {
public:
  Vehicule():m_prix(0){};
    void affiche() const {
        cout << "Ceci est un vehicule." << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Noooo! My code doesn't compile!

Comment: Can you post error message then? Since in MSDN C4700 is described as [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axhfhh6x.aspx) not an error. Also I was able to compile it myself and got only warnings, no errors. clang compiles that as well with to 2 warnings http://liveworkspace.org/code/2ZSD1u$0

Comment: He may have it set to treat warnings as errors, not a bad practice.

Comment: uninitialized local variable 'm' used /
uninitialized local variable 'v' used

Comment: Then probably Benjamin Lindley is right and you have set your compiler to treat warnings as errors. @BenjaminLindley It is indeed not bad practice, but is better to note such things when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio complains, because you do not initialize class' data members (`m_prix`, `m_portes` etc). Also method `affiche` must be virtual and function `presenter` must give its parameter by reference.

```
class Vehicule {
public:
    virtual void affiche() const {
        cout << "Ceci est une voiture." << endl;
    }
};

void presenter(const Vehicle& v) {
    v.affiche()
}
```